# Formulate a Markov Decision Problem for the given strategy

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I was asked to formulate a Markov decision problem to determine the optimal strategy of play where, Assume that you play a chess match with a friend. If you play timid your probability of making a draw is $p=0.8$, the probability of winning is $0.1$ and the chance to lose is $0.1$. If you play bold, you either win with a probability $q=0.45$ or lose. Each win brings one point to the score of the winner. The match consists of $5$ games. If the score is a tie after the fifth game, then a "sudden death" rule is adopted; that is, whoever wins the next game is a winner of the match; if it is a draw again, then the game is repeated with the same rule. Can anyone help me to formulate and understand MDP here?

Comment: If the intention of an "optimal strategy" is to win the match, then there seems to be no case in which one would play timid, as the probability of winning a game is zero...

Comment: how about playing timid with a $0.1$ probability of winning?